# Replace NULL column after SQL UNION of select

Tags: sql-server, union

I am using a `UNION` to combine the results of two select statements. In the returned result, the NULL values need to be filled up:

```
SELECT OrderNumber, OrderName 
FROM tblOrder 
WHERE OrderStatus ='New' 

UNION 

SELECT OrderNumber, OrderName 
FROM tblOrderHistory 
WHERE OrderStatus ='New' 
ORDER BY OrderNumber, OrderName
```

The result:

```
OrderNumber OrderName
---------------------
A001            abc
A001            abc
A001            NULL    
A001            NULL
A001            NULL
B002            xyz
B002            NULL
C003            abc
```

My expected result:

```
OrderNumber OrderName
---------------------
A001            abc
A001            abc
A001            abc
A001            abc
B002            xyz
B002            xyz
C003            abc
```

How to fill up the `NULL` values by matching the order number from `tblOrder`, the `OrderName` value in `tblOrderHistory` rows is always `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick solution, you could consider using `MAX()` as an analytic function here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT OrderNumber, OrderName FROM tblOrder WHERE OrderStatus = 'New'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT OrderNumber, OrderName FROM tblOrderHistory WHERE OrderStatus = 'New'
)

SELECT
    OrderNumber,
    MAX(OrderName) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNumber) OrderName
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    OrderNumber,
    OrderName;
```